# On kubuntu (KDE) all desktop icons can be moved, but not configured. They show a black lock across

Tags: kde, icons, lock, widgets

[image][image][image]No, I haven't locked my widgets. I can move them around freely, I can create them, I can delete them. But I can't resize them and I can't get to their handles.
I searched in here, and found two answers, which did not help. So, I did 'tweak' the widgets in DesktopSettings, to no avail. I did an 'unlock' whereever I could have done one (though none was locked).
The locks looks like a horizontal eight, in black, barely visible on the lower left side of each icon.
I run kubuntu 18.04, daily updated.

The first image shows the lock (?) across the icon. 
The second image shows some widgets that are open for editing, and some, with names in italics, that cannot be modified.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1126650/edit) to include the version of Kubuntu and an image that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I just noticed you edited your question! Are you still in need of an answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks, still in need. Edited, because I was asked to include the kubuntu version.

Comment: With respect to your explanation, I do understand the concept of links. However, until recently I could use the right click option on the launcher. This has stopped working. For a GUI desktop environment, adding links to the desktop or task bar should be possible without any ln -s /from/here /to/there.
I'll try your solution later, however, hoping it will work as expected, and thanks for it!
I have a small screenshot that I'll try to attach. Don't currently see a button here, alas.

Comment: I don't know why you feel you need to "ln -s /from/here /to/there".  Anyway, I don't use the desktop layout mode and don't rely on having icons on the desktop. So it seems my answer doesn't meet your needs. I'll delete my answer and hope that someone who understands your usage comes along.

Comment: Thanks, I said. Don't delete your answer! I wouldn't really know how to do what you propose except by using 'ln'. I'm sort of old-fashioned person, and if I do see something like 'Add to Desktop' and tend to click that, expecting it to work.

Comment: I realized I'm not the best person to answer your question because I haven't ever used the mode you're using. I come from an Openbox background with no desktop at all. Most of the applications I want to launch, I create shortcuts for them. KRunner handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'll only address the desktop icon issue here.

Let's say you drag a *.desktop* file from */usr/share/applications* to your Desktop surface. When you release the mouse, you'll see a small window with the following options (among others):

- Copy Here
- Link Here

If you choose *Copy Here*, the text for the resulting icon will be **normal** and there won't be what you refer to as a "lock" sign. But there maybe an exclamation mark indicating that you need to right-click on the icon and change its permission to *Executable*. Now, if you double-click the icon, the respective application will launch. Such a desktop icon can be further edited.

If you choose *Link Here*, your desktop icon will have italic text, the lock symbol and can't be edited. But you won't need to change any permissions. This is because what you've done is to create a symbolic link. And in Kubuntu, symbolic links are shown in *italics*.

[image: Locked and unlocked desktop icons]